# P-values from Empirical SaddlePoint Approximation

Tags: r, saddlepoint-approximation

I try to implement an empirical saddlepoint approximation to compute p-values. Indeed, I want to compute p-values for a bunch of Score Statistics, asymptotically following a Chi-Square distribution of 1 d.o.f. However, it seems that in the higher distribution tails, asymptotic results offer a inflation of Type I error under the null. I have a bootstrap-based approach which offers some empirical correction.
Due to computational burden, I would like to implement empirical saddlepoint approximation which offers a good control in high tails, since we use larger moments than the first two ones.

I have different family-based statistics and I try to apply SPACox method in my context (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ajhg.2020.06.003 ; https://github.com/WenjianBI/SPACox/blob/master/R/Library.r). However, I cannot have code which runs correctly for all my replicates. Indeed, I obtain lot of NaN values due to negative values either in the squared root or in the log.

Even scaling my statistics I obtain non consistent results. I provide a real-world example from my data.

```r
Stats = c(77.7710275, -11.2945787,  16.0110014,  -6.0676897, -12.0192323,   0.7163944,
-12.8221425,  -7.7549146, -12.0046078, -26.0693617,  14.7595668,  -8.1596877,
32.5089174,  34.0871578)

Var = c(2550.8320,  321.3335,  120.1228,  109.5378,  501.2727,  708.0214,  557.7423,
194.5684,  288.2212, 1108.2906,  108.9224, 2570.4650, 1572.9905,  325.4295)

empirical.MGF = function(S){
  
  idx0 = qcauchy(1:10000/(10001))
  range = c(-100,100)
  idx1 = idx0*max(range)/max(idx0)
  
  cumul = NULL
  c = 0
  
  for(i in idx1)
  {
    c =c+1
    t = i 
    
    #Calculation of empirical MGF
    exp_resid = exp(S*t)
    M0 = mean(exp_resid)
    M1 = mean(S*exp_resid)
    M2 = mean(S^2*exp_resid)
    

    K0 = log(M0)
    K1 = M1/M0
    K2 = (M2*M0-M1^2)/M0^2
    
    cumul = rbind(cumul, c(t, K0, K1, K2))
    if(c %% 1000 == 0) print(paste0("Complete ",c,"/",10000,"."))
  }
  
  #For each point in the interval
  K_org_emp = approxfun(cumul[,1], cumul[,2], rule=2)
  K_1_emp = approxfun(cumul[,1], cumul[,3], rule=2)
  K_2_emp = approxfun(cumul[,1], cumul[,4], rule=2)

  
  var.S = var(S)
  
  return(list("S" = S, "Var.S" = var.S,
              "K.org.emp" = K_org_emp, "K.1.emp"=K_1_emp, "K.2.emp"=K_2_emp, "Cumul"=cumul
              ))
  
}

#We compute empirical MGF for our stats 
t = empirical.MGF(Stats)
out = uniroot(t$K.1.emp,c(-2000,2000), extendInt="yes",maxiter = 200000)
zeta = out$root
    
k1 = t$K.org.emp(zeta)
k2 = t$K.2.emp(zeta)

#Pvalues are computed from Barndorff-Nielson method
temp1 = zeta * Stats - k1
w = sign(zeta) * (2 *temp1)^{1/2}
v = zeta * (k2)^{1/2}

#Two-tailed p-value  
2*pnorm(abs(w + 1/w * log(v/w)), lower.tail = F)
```

I wonder if either I did any code errors or my statistics do not meet approximation assumptions.

Any insights are welcome.